# Multi_index container boost View initialization

Tags: c++11, boost, boost-multi-index

```
class ProcessMaterial
{
   typedef bip::allocator<OrderReceievedT, bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemAllocator;

   typedef bmi::multi_index_container<OrderReceievedT,
        bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<struct NewKey>,
            bmi::composite_key<OrderReceievedT,
            bmi::member<OrderReceievedT, int, &OrderReceievedT::partionID>,
            bmi::member<OrderReceievedT, uint32_t, &OrderReceievedT::MarketSegmentID>,
            bmi::member<OrderReceievedT, uint64_t, &OrderReceievedT::SecurityID>,
            bmi::member<OrderReceievedT, uint64_t, &OrderReceievedT::TradeTimePeriority>,
            bmi::member<OrderReceievedT, uint64_t, &OrderReceievedT::Quantity>
            >>>, ShmemAllocator>
            OrderBookT;
   typedef bmi::nth_index<OrderBookT, 0>::type CompositeKeyOrderViewT;

   bip::offset_ptr<OrderBookT> buyOrderBook[MaxNumStream];
   CompositeKeyOrderViewT& orderView[MaxNumStream];

}
```

i am having problem initalizing the `orderView` in `Constructor`.
things I have tried.

1. Making View to `shared_ptr<CompositeKeyOrderViewT&>`.
2. Simple Obeject.
3. Simple pointer.

I have multiple `OrderBook[10]`, `OrderView[10]`.
ultimately i want like this---->

```
OrderView[2]->insert(OrderRecieved);
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't allow arrays of references. Your compiler would have told you (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1df5574a52fafa88)¹.

You could probably *not* use a reference:

```
std::array<CompositeKeyOrderViewT, 10> orderView;
```

The usual way to create a temporary "index" is using reference_wrapper (see the samples in the BMI docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html#example11

---

¹ Why did I have to type up > 50% of the code to make it complete?

Comment: i found a way.. through `boost::ptr_map`